# Parsing PCL for Text

Tags: c#, printer-control-language

Ok, so I know this is a crappy question but it has been driving me crazy all day...

I have a bunch of files containing raw PCL6/PCL XL code from printing jobs run to our printers. What I need to be able to do is somehow parse them so I can search for specific text.

Does anyone know if this is possible or understand PCL enough to suggest a reason why even on basic prints from say notepad the raw text doesn't seem to be visible within the code?

I suppose I should mention, I need to be able to code this into my C# app. Manual converters or the ability to print the pcl is not going to do what I want.

Comment: No idea, but I'd suggest it's coz printer code doesn't need to be human readable.  This might help:  http://pclhelp.com/pcl-to-pdf/pagetech-convert-pcl-pdf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mcalex is correct, PCL 6 (PCLXL) is a compiled binary.  You can't read it.  You need something that can decompile for you.  [Pagetech](http://www.pagetech.com/) have some solutions for this.  You could also look to convert to some other format where the data might be more readable.  If the source could be generated in PCL 5 or PS you "might" have a better chance or reading the data directly (although not likely).